What is the provenance of these Ninth Doctor minisodes?
I just watched a video on Youtube and was astounded to discover that there are apparently (sort of) a couple of mini Ninth Doctor clips that I'd never known about before!



The first one is from Blue Peter in April 2005. That was in the middle of the Ninth Doctor's tenure, so it makes sense that he would do a cameo in a Blue Peter episode during that period, before his infamous split with the showrunners and all things Doctor Who related. (But why is it so unknown among the fandom? I thought I'd seen all the behind-the-scenes clips and minisodes from that era of the show, like "let's do it tonight" and "bingle-bongle dingle-dangle" and so on, but this is totally new to me.)
The second one is from October 2015, well after the aforementioned split, during the time when Christopher Eccleston refused to have anything to do with Doctor Who. Yet there he is, with a bit less hair than in 2005, but apparently the same old Doctor. But if the "Ten Pieces" referred to in the opening credits is this Ten Pieces, it doesn't even seem to have anything to do with sci-fi.
What gives? Is it just someone on Youtube editing the clip to make it look like it's from Doctor Who, when actually it was the same actor doing something totally un-DW-related? Has he commented on how DW-ish that scene feels? Was it deliberately designed to be so?

Are you missing a link to the second one?

@Valorum the second half of the video is the second video

https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p034s31d - It seems to be Christopher Eccleston introducing it, not Doctor Who.

Each of the 10 pieces has a celeb introduction in the style that they're famous for. https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p034rxy4

I have voted to close. As you have rightly said, these are two completely distinct videos that have been stitched together, decades apart. One is a Doctor Who minisode, the other is from much later, promoting a CBBC event called Ten Pieces.

His "infamous split with the showrunners" happened before the series started airing.

"Another cheat, Eccleston appears as a very Ninth Doctor-like character to introduce viewers to a pice of classical music." - You're not the only person to notice; https://dannylavery9.wordpress.com/2020/05/10/647/

@Valorum that sounds like an answer, not a reason to close...

@fez - They're so obviously from two different sources.

@Valorum but they're still minisodes featuring the same actor, I think they're similar enough that this question could stand.

@AncientSwordRage - Better to ask two distinct questions about the two very distinct videos
